# Print a message on a different location without interrupting input prompt in C

Tags: c

In the case that I have a "MessageLine" to display messages and an input prompt `Input:`
Like this:

```
 MessageLine: Type 123!   
 Input:
```

Then, typing a wrong input, would display "Wrong!" on the `MessageLine`:

```
MessageLine: Wrong!     
Input: somewronginput
```

Then, the user not knowing what to do next, I want the first message to be shown again after 3 seconds, BUT the cursor is still at the input prompt, means the MessageLine would change it's message without affecting the input prompt.

Could it happen to have an independent sequence for my "MessageLine" or whatever solution that would be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <string.h>

void msgline(int msg_var){
    char *msg[]={
        "Type Numbers \"123\"",
        "Wrong! Try Again",
        "Correct! Press Any Key to Exit..."
        };
    gotoxy(25,1);
    clreol();
    printf("Message: %s",msg[msg_var]);// Message Box
}
void main()
{
    char inp[256]={0},
    answr[]="123";
    clrscr();
    do{
        msgline(0); 
        printf("\n\nInput: ");
        clreol();
        scanf("%s",&inp);
        if(!strcmp(inp,answr));
        else{
            memset(inp,0,sizeof(inp));
            msgline(1); // Wrong input
            delay(3000);
            /* delay function also delays the loop
            and the cursor is at the message's end of line */
            }
    }
    while(strcmp(inp,answr));
    msgline(2);  // Correct input
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

This level of control is not part of the standard C definition of the output stream(s).

Depending on your platform, you might be able to use [GNU ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) for instance.